# Migration from Mule to Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel, mule

I am trying to explore is there any tools or any document is available in order to do the Migration from Mule into Apache camel.
please share if anything is available.

Thanks
Arun K

Comment: Nope the two are different. No easy way to do this. Worked on both of them.

Answer (score 1):

After a quick Internet search I suspect the answer is no. Probably their models are two different. You will need to rewrite from scratch the integrations. Note that Camel.appears to favor a Java DSL approach while Mule uses an XML DSL to configure flows.

However if you have a significant number of integrations in Camel XML DSL it might make sense to create a translator  at least to get some base translation that will need to be completed manually.

Comment: Not quiet true. I have done 1000's of integration using the xml dsl of camel. These days Java DSL is favoured but back in 2008 it was all XML.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Camel. Camel web site said that XML DSL is possible but not provided and Java is favoured. That doesn't contradict your comment.

Comment: XML is provided and was preferred by a lot of people for a long time. You are right about it just that XML is provided even today.